# Optimize grid with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to draw an image with some button on the right and at the bottom of it.

The problem is, I don't know which kind of grid I can use.
I don't find any tutorials about it..

Could someone help me with it or give me a tutorial?

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
Builder.load_file('Test.kv')


class Test(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Appa(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Appa().run()
```

and my kv file:

```
<Test>:
    BoxLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            height: 25
            cols: 2
            rows: 2
            # size: root.width * 0.8, root.height * 0.8
            Image:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                size_hint: 1, 1
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1} 
                source: 'Ressources\GraphImage.png'
                size: self.texture_size
            BoxLayout:
                # size_hint: None, 0.2
                size: self.parent.size  # important!
                pos: self.parent.pos  # important!
                GridLayout:
                    # size: root.width * 0.8, root.height * 0.6
                    cols: 1
                    rows: 8
                    height: 5
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
                    Button:
                        size_hint: None,0.1
                        text: 'Button x'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 0.3, None
                Button:
                    # size: 200, 200
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_color: .1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4
                    font_size: 12
                    text: 'Button 1'
                Button:
                    # size: 200, 200
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_color: .8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4
                    font_size: 12
                    text: 'Button 2'
```

As you can see, I tryied a lot of things. Here is the result I'd like to obtain :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<Test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        Image:
            id: image
            size_hint_x: 0.75
            pos: self.pos
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1} 
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            source: 'Ressources\GraphImage.png'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_x: 0.25
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
            Button:
                size_hint: None,0.1
                text: 'Button x'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: None, 0.1
        width: image.width
        pos_hint: {'x':0}
        Button
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: .1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4
            font_size: 12
            text: 'Button 1'
        Button:
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: .8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4
            font_size: 12
            text: 'Button 2'
```

You can adjust `size` and `size_hint` to fine tune.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried it but the results gives buttons 1 and 2 placement at the left of Buttons X.
https://imgur.com/a/W6SW31U

Comment: Yes, and here is the result:

https://imgur.com/a/7GZ8JG4

I but background.png in green to see it better.

Comment: I edited my answer again to include some `size_hint` entries. I believe it should work regardless of the `Image` `source` now.